# Powershell with Selenium: I cannot get the "scroll into view" to work

Tags: powershell, selenium

I need to scroll down the page to the `NEXT` button. Only the `NEXT` button is visible can it clicked on. So I need to get the scroll into view to work.

```powershell
$browser = Start-SeChrome
$browser.Navigate().GoToURL($url)

ForEach ($A_Element in (Find-SeElement -Driver $browser -TagName a))      
   { 
    If ($A_Element.Text -Notlike "Next"){Conitnue} 
    $A_Element.ScrollIntoView()
    #Invoke-SeClick -Element $A_Element       
    #$A_Element.Click() 
    sleep 2
    Break         
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your webpage is designed, you can try to execute JavaScript code within your PowerShell code by trying this:

```
$browser.ExecuteScript("javascript code goes here").
```

You  could try something like:

```
$browser.ExecuteScript("document.scrollTo($($A_Element.Location.X),$($A_Element.Location.Y))")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try executing the javascript code for scrolling:

```
    document.scrollIntoView();
```

execute this js code on your element.
In c# it looks like this:

```
 ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("document.querySelector(arguments[0]).scrollIntoView();", A_Element);
```

Comment: document.scrollIntoView() does not work. In any case document is not defined and it does not reference the position to be scrolled to. The other command you posted is a C# command. I am looking for assistance on Powershell, not c#

Answer (score 0):

I afraid there is something called ScrollIntoView for powershell. However there are ways to scroll down. You can use either of below two methods :

To press down arrow 10 times:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait({{DOWN 10}})
```

To Scroll to a particular location:

```
[int]$horizontalLoc=0
[int]$verticalLoc= 90
browser.Document.parentWindow.scroll($horizontalLoc,$verticalLoc)
```

Comment: I had to load "[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")" and then ran "[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait({{DOWN 10}})" but the Chrome page does NOT scroll. For the command "$browser.Document.parentWindow.scrollto($horizontalLoc,$verticalLoc)" I get an error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"

Comment: Is your page scroll able ? also try once browser.parentwindow.scroll(0, $oIE.document.body.scrollHeight), it will scroll to bottom of page.

Comment: This works for scrolling x px, y px :
$driver.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(x, y)")

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue again while working on a different script and have a better solution this time. These lines can be executed from Powershell directly, which is basically a call to Javascript. Its a combination of the answer provided by @bluecrimson9001 (above) and https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-scrollintoview/

```html
#----Scroll into view----
$browser.executeScript("
  Ref_Element = arguments[0];
  Ref_Element.scrollIntoView();
  ", $A_Element)
#----Scroll into view----
```